# Best way of mapping external error codes to internal codes

Tags: c#

What I mean is that if we get an error code 300 from some service, and need to map it to our own internal error code (say 450), then whats the best way of doing this.

Current system uses constants to keep track of internal errors:

```
public const string ERROR_SOME = "450"; public const string ERROR_ANOTHER = "460";...
```

So I was thinking of just having another set of constants for external errors and then have function for mapping the two:

```
public const string EXT_ERROR_SOME = "300";
public const string EXT_ERROR_ANOTHER = "800";
...
public string MapError(string externalError)
{
    if(externalError == EXT_ERROR_SOME) // can be a switch statement
         return ERROR_SOME;
    else if (externalError == EXT_ERROR_ANOTHER)
         return ERROR_ANOTHER;
    ...
}
```

The question is: **"Is there a better way"?**

Comment: A `Dictionary<string, string>`, perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`Dictionary<string, string>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx):

```
private readonly var errorMap = new Dictionary<string, string>() {
    {EXT_ERROR_SOME, ERROR_SOME},
    ⋮
};

public string MapError(string externalError)
{
    return errorMap[externalError];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a C# question but merely an architectural issue. I wouldn't put that in any code in any language but completely externalize the entire map (as long as its not only this one pair above). And make it somewhat "complete" like

```
"external code : internal code : msg ID"
```

next

```
"language : msg ID : user friendly hint .... "
```

etc. There are several libs for all kind of purposes out there doing this, even in C#.